# Fetching Failed to retrieve size and creation date of file (photo) swift

Tags: swift, image, share

I am trying to get a photo in document directory and share it via `UIActivityViewController` but I get an error.

**Here is my code:**

```
let myURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: fileURLString)
let activityItems: [AnyObject] = [myURL as AnyObject]
let activityViewController: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView=self.view
self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**And here is the error I get:**

> [Fetching] Failed to retrieve size and creation date of file: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “Photo(2).jpg” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:/Users/vittoriapacchiano/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/032FCB8D-422D-4CA2-86FF-22E46361111B/data/Containers/Data/Application/7AC1CF1C-E8EC-4D5D-B8A2-33E96028188F/Documents/Photo(2).jpg -- file:///, NSFilePath=/file:/Users/vittoriapacchiano/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/032FCB8D-422D-4CA2-86FF-22E46361111B/data/Containers/Data/Application/7AC1CF1C-E8EC-4D5D-B8A2-33E96028188F/Documents/Photo(2).jpg, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000034d62e0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

Comment: The error tells you that you don't have that photo in your Documents directory, not much we can help you with. Have you manually checked the content of the directory? Off-topic, you don't need the cast to AnyObject or an array of that type, use `let activityItems = [myURL]`

Comment: I have checked and I find the file. For jpeg and excel I don't have this problem, only for images

Comment: Image is an jpeg, what do you mean? If you have an UIImage object I assume you should add it directly to the array.